# How to send a file programmatically between two android devices using Xamarin Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'am trying to send a text file programmatically from one android device to another via bluetooth. I can pair and connect, I can even send a string, but not a file.

This is my implementation based on the bluetoothchat sample.

CLIENT

```
  private void SendFile()
    {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (service.GetState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, Resource.String.not_connected, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return;
        }


        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream("/storage/sdcard0/test.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            int bufferSize = (int)sourceStream.Length;

            byte[] array = new byte[bufferSize];

            sourceStream.Read(array, 0, bufferSize);

            service.Write(array);


        }
    }
```

SERVICE

```
     public void WriteFile(byte[] @out)
    {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        lock (this)
        {
            if (_state != STATE_CONNECTED)
                return;
            r = connectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized


        r.WriteFile(@out);
    }


    public void WriteFile(byte[] buffer)
        {

            mmOutStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);



        }
```

I'am I missing something in the code? Do i need to set a new target Filestream with a target path for writing? When I ran the code the first time, I saw the bytes to be transfered displayed on the target android device but I did not see the file stored in the file system.

I will appreciate any comments.

Comment: Are you storing the file anywhere? Browsing through the chat code I would assume this would be in 'MyHandler.HandleMessage (Message msg)' located in BluetoothChar.cs.

Comment: So I need to open a new stream eventually with a target path providing the location the file will be stored correct?

Comment: Correct. Using something like StreamWriter would be the quickest and easiest way.

Comment: Ok it seems that adding it in a filestream will not do the work. Anyone has solved a similar issue?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? If yes, could you post it here?